# Absolutely black object in 3D view/texture display

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I have a .blender file that works fine on one computer, but when transferred to another one, the model is displayed in black in 3D view.
A material and a texture exist, the texture preview shows the correct image. The object is rendered correctly. But in the 3D view/Object mode/Texture display method, the figure is absolutely black. Material display method yields the same result, but the Rendered display shows correctly textured object. Shading mode is GLSL.
What gives? Could it be something with the video driver or some other system-specific features?

Here is the system information reported by Blender: https://gist.github.com/Fruchtenstein/ffbc2b5c1c65a48aa97f28d8cd9ab209

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a lightsource (hidden in viewport but visible in render).

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks, but I didn't change the blender file after copying it from the first PC. Isn't light sources' configuration saved in the .blender file?

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the texture files on the new PC, while saving the . blend file go to file and check automatically pack into . blend file. And then try it

Comment: No, the texture file was copied to the new PC, it is visible in texture preview and correctly applied during rendering.